# Is there any Syscall table just like Interrupt Table?

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls, interrupt

Are the system calls like `fork()`, `exit()` saved in some kind of function pointer table , just like the Interrupt Descriptor Table ? where does my OS go when I call my `fork()` or `exit()` ?

I guess this image explains it, but I would like an explanation from a person who really knows what's happening , I don't want knowledge based on my own assumptions.

[image]

Comment: If you're looking for numbers then look at `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` or whatever your arch is. The modules get statically compiled  and then when you call fork that gets translated from glibc. Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: @SailorCire
I assume that this syscall_64.tbl is used only for refference , I found there certain indexes for every sys_call , like sys_fork, sys_read .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fantastic pair of articles on LWN that describe how syscalls work on Linux: "Anatomy of a system call", [part 1](https://lwn.net/Articles/604287/) and [part 2](https://lwn.net/Articles/604515/).

Comment: I like the links shared by you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the following links can help you:

[Interrupts and Interrupt Handling](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/interrupts.html)

[Interrupt Handling](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596005652/ch04s06.html)

[Difference between an IRQ and interrupt vector in linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835714/difference-between-an-irq-and-interrupt-vector-in-linux-kernel)


[Where does an interrupt vector table get stored in Linux?](http://www.quora.com/Where-does-an-interrupt-vector-table-get-stored-in-Linux)